# Scheduling task in Windows involving SCP, SSH

Tags: ssh, scheduled-tasks, scp, wsh

I am running the following script in Windows 8 using Git Bash; works fine when run manually--scp, ssh, etc. all work fine.  But it does not work when put into Task Scheduler.   The Task Scheduler stops at scp ... does not run the scp command. In Scheduler, I am unable to see any error messages or error log (I don't know where to look for log file).

I am using: Run with highest privileges UNCHECKED; Configure for Windows 8;

```
Wscript.echo "Running abc.exe"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = objShell.Run ("C:\abc.exe /S", 1, true)
Wscript.echo "Done Running abc.exe"
WScript.Sleep(5000)
Wscript.echo "Done sleeping"
dim fileSystem
Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Return = objShell.Run ("scp -i c:/users/uname/.ssh/id_dsa /c/data/*.txt admin@svr3.com:/mnt/wnd01/txt",0,true)
Wscript.echo "Uploading file, Return message " & Return
if Return = 0 then
  WScript.Sleep(5000)
  Wscript.echo "Done sleeping on scp"
  fileSystem.MoveFile "C:\data\*.txt","C:\data\archivefiles"
  Return = objShell.Run ("ssh -i c:/users/uname/.ssh/id_dsa admin@svr3.com '/opt/drupal/scripts/import_raw.sh wnd01'",0,true)
end if
Wscript.echo "Running DB script on server, Return message " & Return
```

Any help in figuring out what may be going on would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually calling executing abc.exe and then upload the files into server move the files to specific location in your server.